# Recuperar o conteudo de uma JCombo em outra classe

Tags: java

Preciso capturar o conteudo desta Jcombo que tera porta (com1, com2. etc)
para na outra classe imprimir  setar a porta para impressão. Nao estou conseguindo.

```
public class Form1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
 Imprimir imprimir;

 JComboBox JComboPorta;
/**
 * Creates new form Form1
 */
public Form1() {
    initComponents();


public JComboBox getJComboPorta() {
    return JComboPorta;
}
```

/// dentro do InitComponenst... inicializa com as portas
jComboPorta.setModel(newDefaultComboBoxModel(SerialPortList.getPortNames()));

e na classe Imprimir como fazer?

```
public class Imprimir {


public void imprimir_cheque() throws InterruptedException
{
         SerialPort serialPort;
         Form1 form1;
 try

    {
        form1.jComboPorta.getSelectedItem();????

        serialPort = new SerialPort ("COM3");
```

Answer (score 0):

Se são classes distintas, ou seja, se encontram em arquivos diferentes, e não se trata de um elemento estático, você irá precisar de uma instância da classe `Form1` em `Imprimir` para acessar o componente.

Supondo que você instancie e utilize a classe `Imprimir` dentro da classe do JFrame, você poderia conseguir acessar o componente através do método `getJComboPorta()` que você criou, simplesmente alterando a assinatura do método conforme abaixo:

```
public void imprimir_cheque(Form1 form1) throws InterruptedException
{
         SerialPort serialPort;
         //Form1 form1; <-- desnecessário agora
 try

    {
        Object o = form1.getJComboPorta().getSelectedItem();

        serialPort = new SerialPort ("COM3");
```

E na hora de chamar esse método dentro da classe `Form1`, você irá passar a própria instância da tela, através do `this`:

```
imprimir.imprimir_cheque(this);
```